# PyQt Window always not responding

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I am newbie to Qt GUI and I am trying to run this very simple script using PyQt4 on Python 2.7.11. The problem is that when I run the script the window is displayed but when I click on it I get a not responding message.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window  = QtGui.QWidget()

window.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)

window.setWindowTitle('Preview')

window.show()
```

[image: not responding]
[image: pythonnw]

**Note:** I am on a windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add `app.exec_()` at the end. This will start the Qt event loop.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window  = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
window.setWindowTitle('Preview')
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked also with some other codes I have :).